# Парсер скачивает не прогруженные картинки

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Сделал парсер, но он скачивает не прогруженные картинки.
Выводит список из таких элементов /themes/ptk/assets/images/ptk-preload.png. А мне нужно из таких: "https://ptk-svarka.ru/storage/app/uploads/public/5bd/064/59a/thumb_86_305_305_0_0_crop.jpg"

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    image = []
    for item in items:
        image.append(
            item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('src'),
            )
    return  image

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        img = get_image(html.content)
        print(img)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изображения в списке все одинаковы и ссылаются на тот же файл. Загрузка картинок делается с помощью javascript.

Взгляните на конкретный товар, в атрибуте `data-src` находится ссылка на изображение. Используйте его вместо `src`:

```
item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src')
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло